# Using generic template member in a class C++

Tags: c++, templates

I'm creating class that has a templated object (`Item<T>`) as a member, basically like this:

```
class myClass
{
 int other_int;

 public:
 int member_function();
 vector<Item<T>> vec;
 };
```

Currently, I have `Item<string>`, but I need to be able to use it with non string objects. Is there a way to do this without templating `myClass` (which would obviously be a lot of work for a complicated class)?

Comment: _"Is there a way to do this without templating myClass"_ Nope.

Comment: Why is it a lot of work if that one data member is the only that's going use the template parameter? A search and replace ought to be enough. And no, there is no other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your class will only use Item< string>, you may try:

```
class myClass
{
    int other_int;

    public:
    int member_function();
    vector<Item<string>> vec;
};
```

But if you want any other type of Item in the vector, the answer is No, there is no magic solutions.